# Termite inspection and finished basement ceiling

Tags: basement, pest-control, termite

I have termites in my yard, not too far from my house.  (Locale:  Massachusetts, USA.)  So I want to get an inspection and treatment.  (The house was built in 1937; I bought it in 2014, and as usual with these things there's no record of when it was last inspected/treated.)

I know little about these things, but I would assume that the inspector would want to look at the joists in the basement ceiling, since that's where there's a lot of wood.  But at some point in the home's history some genius decided it would be a good idea to finish the ceiling with plaster over metal mesh.

Am I incorrect that those joists need to be exposed for a thorough termite inspection?

Comment: What did local termite inspection companies say when you asked them?

Comment: @mmathis:  Haven't asked.